# Troubles posting a JSON value using Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, postman

I am trying to make a post request using json but in postman the request is successful only if I make the request like this: `email@example.com`. If I make a request using the standard JSON format `{"email":"email@example.com"}` I get "invalid email id". I should mention that content type `application/json` header is checked in postman, and I am making the request in body/raw.

I have tried messing with `@RequestBody`/`@RequestParam` annotations, using `consumes = "application/json"` but I am unsuccessful and I couldn't find a similar issue after lots of googling either.

my controller:

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@PostMapping(value = "/forgot-password", consumes = "application/json")
public String forgotPassword(@RequestBody String email) {

    String response = userService.forgotPassword(email);

    if (!response.startsWith("Invalid")) {
        response = "http://localhost:8080/reset-password?token=" + response;
    }
    return response;
}
```

user service:

```
public String forgotPassword(String email) {

    Optional<User> userOptional = Optional
            .ofNullable(userRepository.findByEmail(email));

    if (!userOptional.isPresent()) {
        return "Invalid email id.";
    }

    User user = userOptional.get();
    user.setToken(generateToken());
    user.setTokenCreationDate(LocalDateTime.now());

    user = userRepository.save(user);

    return user.getToken();
}
```

Comment: You said the `@RequestBody` should be a `String`, *not* something that would map to an object with an `email` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, the `@RequestBody` annotation maps the HttpRequest body to a transfer or domain object.You need to put object instead of String

Your endpoint should be like Below.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/forgot-password", consumes = "application/json")
public String forgotPassword(@RequestBody EmailDto email) {

    String response = userService.forgotPassword(email.getEmail);
    // ...
    return response;
}
```

Your DTO should be like below

```
public class EmailDto {

    private String email; 
    //Getters and Setters      
}
```

Comment: I get an error cause I don't have an @id annotation in the emailed class, what should I put as the id? The email class is only a column of the 'users' table it doesn't have an id of its own...

Answer (score 0):

You should have Email model with string property `email`.

```
public EmailPayload {

  String email;
.....
```

Then it will work (it will fit json you provided).
Ofcouse class name can be different, only thing that must match is email property, then in your Controller your `@RequestBody` will be this class, and not `String` you have now.